# How to use bulk_load in apache airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I have apache airflow 2.1.4 and postgres database.
I need to insert multiple rows at a time. So I am going to use bulk_load method of PostgresHook but get error everytime.

```
data = pd.read_csv(open(filepath, 'rb'))
buffer = StringIO()
buffer.write(data.to_csv(index=None, header=None, sep='\t'))
buffer.seek(0)
schema_table = 'schema.table'
with PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='my_pg_database'):
    PostgresHook.bulk_load(table=schema_table, tmp_file=buffer)
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/dags/my_python_file.py", line 76, in <module>
my_func(filepath=my_file, target_schema=schema, target_table=table)
File "/home/airflow/dags/my_python_file.py", line 39, in my_func
with PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='my_pg_database'):
AttributeError: __enter__
```

I couldn't even find some examples of bulk_load usage. Would appriciate any clue. Thank you.

Comment: The only example I have found here: https://python.hotexamples.com/ru/examples/airflow.hooks.postgres_hook/PostgresHook/bulk_load/python-postgreshook-bulk_load-method-examples.html

But I didn't get how they provide database coonection id, table name and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres Hook (and any other hooks really) are not "context managers". You cannot use `with:`  to use them.

Something like that should work:

```
postgres_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='my_pg_database')
postgres_hook.bulk_load(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/dags/my_python_file.py", line 76, in <module>
    my_func(filepath=my_file, target_schema=schema, target_table=table)
  File "/home/airflow/dags/my_python_file.py", line 45, in kplus_to_marts
    PostgresHook.bulk_load(table=schema_table, tmp_file=buffer)
TypeError: bulk_load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Please read the example - it's different than your. It's pretty basic python thing to run stuff as object method rather than class method. I am afraid asking question on Stack Overflow when some basic Python knowledge would answer it, is I think bad way of learning Python